# Is it possible to update the interval timer within the function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

It's been a full day now and I still can't seem to fix this issue.

I working on a project for my website and I just need to know how to change the interval timer  from an IF statement within the interval it self.

The interval will check if there is an error from the $.post and if there is, it will display the first system error. (aswell as incrementing another variable to proceed to error #2.

3 seconds later, error #2 will show. That's exactly how I want it. However, the interval keeps staying at 3 seconds and it's not working no matter what I do.

```
_staffIntervalID = 3000;
serverError = 0;

staffMsg = setInterval(function() { 

        if(isInChat == true) {
        $.post('./slivechat.php', {staff:"true"}, function(data) {
        if(data == "") return;

        $('#display_msg').append( + nl2br(data) + "<br />");
        $('#display_msg').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');

        })
                .error(function() {
                 serverError++;

                if(serverError == 1) {
                $('#display_msg').append("<span style='color: red;'>System</span>: An error occured whilst we tried to fetch staff response. Please wait while I try to fix the this problem.<br />");
                _staffIntervalID = 12000;
                } else if(serverError == 2) {
                $('#display_msg').append("<span style='color: red;'>System</span>: There seems to be an error, please check your conection. Or wait a few more seconds for the final verdict.<br />");
                _staffIntervalID = 24000;
                } else if(serverError >= 3) { 
                $('#display_msg').append("<span style='color: red;'>System</span>: Due to technical difficulties we are closing this chat. Please try again later! <br />");
                clearInterval(staffMsg);
                }

        $('#display_msg').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');
        console.log("ServerError: " + serverError + " timer: " + _staffIntervalID);
        });
        }

    }, _staffIntervalID);
```

Even on console.log it shows that the timer has changed, but it keeps updating every 3.

Really hoping I can get this fixed soon!

Ps- Javascript is not my main language, PHP is. So if you do have a fix, please try give an example too.

Comment: Use setTimeout instead of setInterval and change the duration depending on your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using an anonymous function and resetting the timer

```
serverError = 0;

var staffMsg = setInterval(CheckError, 3000);
function CheckError () {

    if (isInChat == true) {
        $.post('./slivechat.php', {
            staff: "true"
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == "") return;

            $('#display_msg').append(+nl2br(data) + "<br />");
            $('#display_msg').animate({
                scrollTop: $(document).height()
            }, 'slow');

        })
            .error(function () {
            serverError++;

            if (serverError == 1) {
                $('#display_msg').append("<span style='color: red;'>System</span>: An error occured whilst we tried to fetch staff response. Please wait while I try to fix the this problem.<br />");
                clearTimeout(staffMsg);
                staffMsg = setInterval(CheckError, 12000);
            } else if (serverError == 2) {
                $('#display_msg').append("<span style='color: red;'>System</span>: There seems to be an error, please check your conection. Or wait a few more seconds for the final verdict.<br />");
                clearTimeout(staffMsg);
                staffMsg = setInterval(CheckError, 24000);
            } else if (serverError >= 3) {
                $('#display_msg').append("<span style='color: red;'>System</span>: Due to technical difficulties we are closing this chat. Please try again later! <br />");
                clearInterval(staffMsg);
            }

            $('#display_msg').animate({
                scrollTop: $(document).height()
            }, 'slow');
            console.log("ServerError: " + serverError + " timer: " + _staffIntervalID);
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change the interval period.

But you can do it this way instead:

```
var _staffIntervalID = 3000;
setTimeout(function() {
    // your code here
    setTimeout(arguments.callee,_staffIntervalID);
},_staffIntervalID);
```

Comment: Sorry buddy, but that code has kind of baffled me :$. I don't mean to ask for spoon feeding, but could you be a little specific? the "setTimeout(arguments.callee,_staffIntervalID);" within the setTime() pretty much confused me.

Comment: `arguments.callee` refers to the current function. In this case, the function that's being passed to the timeout. With this you can just update the `_staffIntervalID` variable and it will update the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the setInterval method won't change the timer value by just reseting the timer value.

What you should do is clear the timer and use a function name as a reference for your function like :

```
var delay = 1000, now = new Date().valueOf();
var timer = setInterval(function loop()
{
    console.log(now - new Date.valueOf());

    delay += 1000;
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(loop, delay);

}, delay);
```

or (with a timeout) :

```
var delay = 1000, now = new Date().valueOf();
var timer = setTimeout(function loop()
{
    console.log(now - new Date.valueOf());

    delay += 1000;
    timer = setTimeout(loop, delay);

}, delay);
```

Note that putting an ajax call in a timer might be a good idea. You should rather wait for the response to call again.

Comment: Um... Isn't clearing the interval and setting a new one every time... just the same as setting a new timeout?

Comment: arguments.calle is not standard, would be better to name the anonymous function and execute it by the name

Answer (score 0):

Even if you change the variable _staffIntervalID does not mean that the setInterval is gonna change, in order to make it work you need to do a clearInterval and run a new setInterval with the new value